# What is wrong with this trigonometric integral?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

[image: h]

Where does the minus sign come from when splitting the integral? Or is it wrong?

Comment: We probably need to know what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: @Suzet I'm guessing $u(x,\,0)$.

Comment: Yes sorry, f(x) = u(x,0)

Comment: Should be +. It comes from copying and pasting a previous problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minus sign between the two split integrals is incorrect. The author then makes a second mistake but still manages to arrive at the correct solution at the end of the calculation.

\begin{align}B_n&=\frac{2}{L}\int_0^Lf(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\,dx\\&=
\frac{2}{L}\left(\int_0^{L/2}f(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\,dx\color{red}+\int_{L/2}^Lf(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\,dx\right)\\&=\frac{2}{L}\left(\int_0^{L/2}\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\,dx\color{red}+2\int_{L/2}^L\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\,dx\right)\\&=
\frac{2}{L}\left(-\frac{L}{n\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big|_0^{\color{red}{L/2}} -  \frac{2L}{n\pi}\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big|_{L/2}^L\right)\\&=
-\frac{2}{n\pi}\left(\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big|_0^{\color{red}{L/2}}+2\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}\Big|_{L/2}^L \right)\\&=
-\frac{2}{n\pi}\left(\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}-1+2\cos n\pi-2\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)\\&=
\frac{2}{n\pi}\left(1-2(-1)^n+\cos\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the fact that calculations continue with the same overall sign on each evaluated integral, the $-2$ between the integrals is likely to be a misprint. If it were a $+2$, it would make sense given the definition of $u$.